# Apple Developer Certificate

Tags: ios

I am wanting to put my iPhone app on a test device. I read somewhere where I need a developer certificate. Do I need to be in a paid developer program to create a developer certificate and provisioning profile?

Comment: Yes you need paid developer certificate if you need to send build over others iphone. If you have to test on your iPhone device then no need of paid developer account. Just sign up on Developer account and add to your xcode. You can run your app on device using iphone cable without paid account.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you need to be a paid developer. Basically is a two-step process:

1. Create your Apple developer account and join the iOS Developer Program. It will cost you $99/year and it allows you to test your apps on a device and distribute your apps in the app store. You can go [here to](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enroll/) register.

2. Follow [these](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/distributing-your-app-to-registered-devices) steps in order to provision your test device

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You need to sign up with the developer program to debug on devices and deploy to test devices.

Answer (score 1):

You must first sign up to be an offical developer here:
[iOS Developer Program](http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/)

Then you must register devices via the provisioning portal:
[iOS Provisioning Portal](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ProvisioningDevelopment/ProvisioningDevelopment.html)

Answer (score 0):

@simm0t is correct, you do need a paid IOS developer account. You can get one of those [on developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com/programs/start/register/create.php).

Also, if you simply cannot go through that process for whatever reason you can develop your app with a dummy certificate/provisioning (you can find these online) and upload to a jailbroken device, then install your app with Installous. While I was a student and couldn't afford a paid IOS dev account this is how I was able to learn to make iPhone apps and test them on my iPod touch.