# How to test the iPad app in iPad hardware (not in simulator)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I am a Beginner in IOS Development.After I'm done with build and test on iPad simulator.I would like to figure out:

1.What is difference between testing and deploying app on iPad?

2.How we can test or deploy iPad app without developer license and registering iPad development-device ?

3.Can test ipad app on ipad hardware using [testflight app](https://testflightapp.com/sdk) without payment. How?

I have visited various link but it didn't clarified me ?

[How to test the iPad app in iPad hardware (not in simulator)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767140/how-to-test-the-ipad-app-in-ipad-hardware-not-in-simulator)

[How can I test my iPad app on my actual iPad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338482/how-can-i-test-my-ipad-app-on-my-actual-ipad/3338622#3338622)

[Personal iPhone application without paying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617992/personal-iphone-application-without-paying)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Apple Developer Certificate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8042139/apple-developer-certificate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1.How i can test app on iPad hardware?

Buy an iPad device and start testing on it.

> 2.What is difference between testing and deploying app on iPad?

1. Certificates Development vs Production
2. Provisioning profile Development vs Production
3. Push notification token is different

> 3.How we can test or deploy iPad app without developer license and registering iPad development-device ?

No you cannot without developer account, as the answers you linked all said you will need to pay a membership to apple of `$99` as of now I believe.

Answer (score 0):

In my suggestion,

**Don't buy an iPad, instead buy an iPhone6+, why?**

> You can use it as phone even when you're not doing a test. If an app running well (in most cases) will run on iPad (except some UI objects which you can easily test in simulator). This seems funny but you will happy with 6+.
>
> Even you can buy iPod 5th generation. Which are little cheap.

**No developer account? Not need.**

> If you've a device then ask your friend (who have iOS developer account) to add your UDID into their account and grab you provisioning profile and certificate. For a registered account one can add 100 devices. Mostly they don't have this much of devices. If you're a good friend then he may not say NO. Even you can offer him for a treat (a beer or coffee) for this.

**No good friend / No Device ?** **Still don't worry**.

> Either you can purchase a device (which you want) and open-up a account, and Yes you'll be happy forever (at least for a year, you've to repay after one year).

OR

> There're several online testing services from which you can choose the best for you. Mostly they will charge in minutes they test your app. I seen one service which give 200 minutes/month @ $20 (or 1200 minutes/month @ $100). For a very small app this can be enough (after proper unit testing in simulator by you).

**At last**,
Having a device and account will be a long time investment. If you have both you can test and upload (your own apps too) on AppStore. But at minimum investment cost of $700 to 800 .